# socket.io not sending to room using socket.to('myroom').emit

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am using socket.io 1.4.0.

I am trying to send a message to put the client in a room called 'myroom', then send a message to the room from the client and then get the response from the room. However I get no response from using

```
        socket.to('myroom').emit('message', 'what is going on, party people?');
```

Here is my client code:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
   // Connected, join the booking room for to receive messages for this room
   socket.emit('room', 'myroom');

});


  socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });

  socket.emit('booking room message', {roomid: 'myroom', message: 'hello'});
```

Here is my server code:

```
// Set up the Socket.IO server
var io = require("socket.io")(server)
    .use(function(socket, next) {
        // Wrap the express middleware
        sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
    })
    .on("connection", function(socket) {
        console.log(socket.request.session);

        if (socket.request.session.passport) {


            var userId = socket.request.session.passport.user;

            //Sign up client for the room from client side.
            socket.on('room', function(room) {
                socket.join(room);
                console.log(userId + ' has joined booking room: ' + room);
            });

            //make a room for this user
            socket.join(userId);

            console.log("User ID: " + userId + " connected. socketID: " + socket.id);

            socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                console.log("User ID: " + userId + " disconnected.");
            });


            socket.on('booking room message', function(data) {
                console.log('message sent from browser to a room');
                console.log(data);
                socket.to('myroom').emit('message', 'what is going on, party people?');
            });


        }
    });
```

I get a message back from the server as expected when I use :

```
socket.emit('message', 'what is going on, party people?');
```

So there is something wierd going on with the join room function. A couple of things to note, I have some middleware tha gets the ID from express - dont think that is having any impact. Also I create a seperate room for the userID.

Can a user be in two rooms at once? I am not sure what is causing this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

it seemed that neither to or in will send the response back to the same client. The code above did send to other clients in the room however.